# Creating a table for each student. Is it considered a bad practice?

Tags: mysql, database

i have hit a road bump where i need to list all the current courses for students and instructors and i have 2 tables one of them is called students and the second one is called courses. I was thinking of creating a field for students called courses and then separating entries with a comma so i can use the WHERE IN clause but creating a table for each student is much easier.

Comment: Yes it is. "m to m" is the buzzword you search :D

Comment: make an `attend` table that join student to courses

Comment: why would you separate things with commas in a database? use more columns...

Comment: Yes, it is considered a bad practice.  A very bad practice.  One of the most common misunderstandings that novices have about databases.  Whenever you think that you need multiple tables of the same kind, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Piglet No: More rows. Ending up with a table with `course1`, `course2`, ... columns is just as bad as comma separated values.

Comment: Search for _many to many_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was thinking of creating a field for students called courses and then separating entries with a comma

Bad idea, and you're certainly not the first to have it.

> creating a table for each student is much easier

Worse idea, and you're certainly not the first to have it.

Don't create database structures that require you to *parse* information from disorganized blobs.  And *definitely* don't create database structures that require you to *change the structure* every time data changes.

What you're describing, the relationship between `Student` and `Course`, is called a many-to-many relationship.  To achieve it, all you need is a "linking table" between the two entities.  Consider something like this:

```
Student
----------
ID (PK)
Name

Course
----------
ID (PK)
Name
```

Simple enough representation of those two entities.  Now all you need is a third table to connect them in a many-to-many relationship:

```
StudentCourse
----------
ID (PK)
StudentID (FK)
CourseID (FK)
```

A few things to note:

1. The name of the table doesn't have to follow this convention, this is just a common practice.  You can call it anything you like.  `Enrollment` might be a good name for this as it grows into its own entity.
2. This doesn't *need* its own `ID (PK)`, its primary key could be a composite of the two foreign keys (since each pair thereof should also be unique in this domain).
3. This can quickly grow into its own entity if it has more data than just the relationship.  For example, if there is specific information about a student's enrollment in a course which is specific to the combination of the two, but not specific to either entity itself.  A registration number of some kind, a date/time of enrollment, etc.  This table would become its own entity alongside the other two and be more than just a structural linking table.

Answer (score 5):

As you have a many-to-many mapping, consider using a linking table with `student_id` and `course_id` columns.